# Displaying Flash messages in Node-js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, my login page is a pop-up, which pops up when I click on 'Tickets' button. On successfully logging in, it redirects me to the 'Tickets' Page. That part is working fine.

I've added 2 error-handlings, one when the credentials added don't match in the backend and the other when there's no email or password added. So, when I try these two, it redirects me to my homepage and the message that's supposed to be flashed isn't flashed but instead on clicking the 'Tickets' again, the flass-message is displayed then. So, I want that when I've done an error in adding the credentials, it stays on the same page and flashes the error message then and there on top**

[image: I entered wrong credentials, it redirected me to my homepage and on clicking the 'Ticket's again, it shows the message here]

I'm using connect-flash and express-session

This is my controller for login

```
exports.login = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        if (!email || !password) {
                req.flash('error', 'Please Provide an email or password!');
                return res.redirect("/");
                
        }
        connection.query('SELECT * from users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (err, results) => {
            // console.log(results[0]);
            if (!results || !results.length || !await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password)) {
                req.flash('error', 'Email or password doesn\'t match!');
                return res.redirect("/");

            } else {
                // req.flash('success', 'Successfully logged in!');
                 return res.redirect("/ticketform");
               
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

**And this is an extract from login.ejs where I'm using flash and session**

```
<section id="login-form">
        <% if(error.length>0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger message"> 
            <!-- bootstrap class -->
            <%= error %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <% if(success.length>0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-success message">
                <!-- bootstrap class -->
            <%= success %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <<form class="login-form-content" action="/public/login" method="POST">>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password">
                  </div>
                 
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary "><a class="signupbtn">Login</a></button>
                  </div>
          </form>
    </section>
    <script>
        let message = $('.message');
            if (message.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    message.fadeOut('slow');
                }, 3000);
                // setInterval(() => {
                //     location.replace("/ticketform");
                // },3500);
            }
      </script>
```

To stay on the same page, instead of `return res.redirect("/");` I tried, `//res.status(204).send();` but this didn't work either. I think that the fact that this is a pop-up instead of a page, is what might be causing trouble. I also made a similar thing for signup, but that had its own page on the web (/register). Right now, this pop up is displayed on the homepage only (/).
Also, this is my first time designing a website, very new to Nodejs.

Comment: you'll need to use ajax to post the form, then return json to determine if to add the alert or other errors to the dom, you can use `req.xhr` serverside to determine if its an ajax request and respond accordingly with the right content/redirect etc